# Android - Webview in fullscreen mode how to hide notificationbar if softkeybaord is present

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard, statusbar

I have developed a small Android app using a webview. All Android UI elements such as notificationbar, statusbar, actionbar are hidden using:

```
  private void hideSystemUI() {
// Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
// Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
// doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

}

If I open an HTML formular and tap into one input field, the softkeyboard shows up.
But then also the Android notificationbar appears, what I don't want.
(see images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnCtD.jpg)
If I close the softkeyboard by the upper left key on the softkeyboard, the notificationbar still remains open and occupies a part of my title bar on my HTML page.
How can I hide the notificationbar if softkeyboard is opened?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Call this in onCreate:

```
private void setupFullscreenMode() {
    View decorView = setFullscreen();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    setFullscreen();
                }
            });
}

private View setFullscreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    return decorView;
}
```

Also override onWindowsFocusChanged:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        setFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does work for webview's input because of the soft keyboard is shown with the navigation bar. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/28060917/1030870 for a workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by doing this:

```
    mWebView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI(); // setup fullscreen
        }
    });
```