# Disable soft buttons when inflating a fullscreen layout from service

Tags: android, android-service, layout-inflater

I have a service which (in `onCreate()`) inflates a layout which is fullscreen (kind of a custom lockscreen). I would like to disable (hide) soft keys (return, home, recents) and possibly also status bar.

I know about [immersive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115600/android-hide-navigation-bar-stay-in-immersive-mode-with-soft-keyboard-appearance) but that works in an Activity while I only have a Service. I designed it as a service so the previous app still runs below uninterrupted. The service looks like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        View vLockscreen = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_lock, null);

        wm.addView(vLockscreen, params);
    }
```

How could I achieve full lockscreen functionality?