# Android Hide Navigation Bar/Stay in Immersive Mode when Button clicked

Tags: android, android-immersive

What seems like a really simple thing is causing me a few issues.  I have looked at the solutions from:

[Android Hide Navigation Bar/Stay in Immersive Mode with Soft Keyboard Appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115600/android-hide-navigation-bar-stay-in-immersive-mode-with-soft-keyboard-appearance).

I have a simple activity with a ImageButton on.  I want to be in Immersive Mode.  I call the following method onCreate.

**Issue**
The first click on the screen always brings up the navigation bar and does not fire the click handler.  Is there a simple / less hacky way to stop this

```
 public void hideNavigationBar()
        {
            final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

            decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember to add this method:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

This automatically keeps it hidden, even when buttons or the screen is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was being rather silly (been a while since I done Android)

This fixes the issue:

```
private void hideNavigationBar()
    {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
        // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
        // a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
        // hide the navigation bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    }
```