# Flutter: How to show onscreen keyboard without android's bottom navigation bar on focusing a textfield?

Tags: dart, flutter, overlay, on-screen-keyboard

If you focus a `TextField` the system overlays will accompany the onscreen keyboard despite calling `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` before and immediately after the focus change happened. Any way to change that?

For Clarity: I am referring to the onscreen bottom navigation bar that is provided by android when phones have no physical buttons. In flutter, when you tap on a textfield, the onscreen keyboard comes up, and with it this navigation bar is being forced in. I'd like to hide it, because it's sometimes unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry but to me your question is not clear, what bottom navigation bar has to do with on screen keyboard?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I added further explanation to the question. I hope you'll understand it now.

Comment: It's crystal clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, You can't hide it. This is the default system behavior (you can't change it) to show the navigation bar when on screen keyboard is visible to the user.

It is provided so that the user can press the back button from the navigation bar in order to hide the Keyboard. So, it will stay there forever as long as keyboard is visible to the user.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Well, now I realize that it's probably a good practise to keep it visible on devices without physical navigation buttons.